# Perform intersection with joins

Tags: sql-server, join, intersection

In following stored procedure I want to filter employees based on certain condition..
Employee will have one primary skill and any number of secondary skills
following is a schema of skill table.

```
id => int
EmpId => int 
TechnologyId => int
isPrimarySkill => bit
Proficiency => int
```

how can I fetch employee based on multiple secondary skill and primary skill,
it is giving null..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SearchEmployees]
 @Name varchar(40) = null,
 @ManagerId int = null,
 @EmployeeType int = null,
 @Location int = null,
 @ExpInMonths int = null,
 @PrimarySkills int = null,
 @PrimarySkillsProficiency int = null,
 @SecondarySkills XML = null,
 @AvailableAfter int = null
 AS

DECLARE @TSecondarySkills TABLE (ID int) 

BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION TransactionName

        INSERT INTO @TSecondarySkills (ID) 
        SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
        FROM   @SecondarySkills.nodes('/TSecondarySkills/id') as ParamValues(ID)     


        SELECT E.Id as EmpId,(E.FirstName +' '+ E.LastName) as EmpName from Employee E
            LEFT JOIN EmployeeSkill ES ON ES.EmployeeId = E.Id
            LEFT JOIN @TSecondarySkills TSS ON ES.TechnologyId = TSS.ID AND ES.IsPrimarySkill = 0
            LEFT JOIN ResourceAllocation RA ON RA.EmployeeId = E.Id AND RA.EndDate >= GETDATE() AND RA.StartDate <= GETDATE()
        Where 
            ((@ManagerId IS NULL) OR (E.ManagerId = @ManagerId )) AND
            ((@Name IS NULL) OR (E.FirstName LIKE '%'+@Name+'%'  OR E.LastName LIKE '%'+@Name+'%' OR (E.FirstName+' '+E.LastName LIKE '%'+@Name+'%' ))) AND
            ((@EmployeeType IS NULL) OR (E.EmployementTypeId = @EmployeeType )) AND
            ((@Location IS NULL) OR (E.LocationId = @Location )) AND
            ((@PrimarySkills IS NULL) OR (ES.IsPrimarySkill = 1 AND TechnologyId = @PrimarySkills )) AND
            ((@PrimarySkillsProficiency IS NULL) OR (ES.IsPrimarySkill = 1 AND ES.Proficiency =  @PrimarySkillsProficiency )) AND
            ((@ExpInMonths IS NULL) OR (dbo.GetExpInMonthByEmpID(E.Id) >= @ExpInMonths)) AND
            ((@SecondarySkills IS NULL) OR (TSS.ID IS NOT NULL)) AND
            ((@AvailableAfter IS NULL AND RA.EndDate IS NULL) OR (DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),RA.EndDate) <= @AvailableAfter) OR (RA.EndDate IS NULL)) 

        GROUP BY 
            E.FirstName,E.LastName, E.Id


        COMMIT TRANSACTION TransactionName

  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
     RollBack Transaction TransactionName
  End Catch
END
```

Comment: It would be useful if you mention the RDBMS you are using in the tags

Comment: Copy from school Paste in stackoverflow

Comment: I am weak in SQL Server ..

Comment: What data do you have in the tables, and what do you expect the results to be?